# Azure DevOps 'Run Only Impact Tests' doesn't work with XUnit Tests?

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, xunit, impact-analysis

I have an ASP.net Web API project (.NET Framework v4.6.2) where I have written unit test cases using XUnit.

I have created a build pipeline in Azure DevOps with '*Run only impacted tests*' set to *checked*. Also, my Visual Studio test version is set to *2.** in my test assemblies.

I have tried to run my mock tests (No data driven test cases) to check that only impacted test run but all the tests run.

I had hard luck finding the solution for It. Can anyone know how to do it right?

I have read this article and and done setting accordingly, but failed.

Comment: Hi. Which article did you read and follow? Can you provide a link to it?